# Separar ocorrências do join em múltiplas colunas

Tags: sql-server

tenho um banco de dados de um supermercado e preciso fazer um select nas informaçoes dos produtos, o problema esta na parte dos codigos, pois cada produto possu 3 codigos cada, eentao tenhos 2 tabelas, a tabela dbo.produto que me traz a informaçao dos produtos e a tablea dbo.produt_sinonimo que me traz os codigos

exemplo tabela produto

```
id    nome
1  |   pao
2  |   leite
3  |   farinha
```

exemplo tabela de codigos

```
id    codigo
1   |   110
1   |   111
1   |   123
2   |   156
2   |   129
2   |   234
3   |   354
3   |   456
3   |   786
```

preciso de um select que me traga a informaçao dos id's agrupada, e cada codigo em uma respectiva coluna, mais ou menos assim

```
id     nome       codigo1   codigo2   codigo3
 1  |  pao      |    110   |   111   |   123
 2  |  leite    |    156   |   129   |   234
 3  |  farinha  |    354   |   456   |   786
```

é possivel fazer esse select dessa forma ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi falta um dado na tabela de código para saber o que é 1, 2 ou 3, seria a sequencia ? Pesquisou por PIVOT em SQL ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: realmente nao tem nada que identifique, essa ta sendo minha maior dificuldade, até mesmo pra usar o pivot

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: deu certo d+ mano, vou postar a forma que fiz como resposta pq pode ajudar outras pessoas, mas vlw aee, ajudou muito

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o comando UNPIVOT.

Usando a tabela "student" como exemplo:

A consulta SQL que eu mencionei anteriormente usa o comando UNPIVOT para transformar a tabela "student" em uma tabela "despivotada". A tabela "student" original tem três colunas: name, score1 e score2. Com o uso do UNPIVOT, as notas (score1 e score2) são transformadas em linhas separadas e uma nova coluna chamada "subject" é adicionada, indicando de qual coluna (score1 ou score2) a nota veio.

SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT name, score1, score2 FROM student)
UNPIVOT
(score FOR subject IN (score1, score2))

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *"Usando a tabela "student""*  student? *"A consulta SQL que eu mencionei anteriormente"* não mencionou nada anteriormente, não há um erro ai ou copiou isso de algum lugar Eraldo? o exemplo poderia ser adaptado à pergunta, que é "product", pra ajudar a responder melhor à pergunta

Comment: O que a pergunta pede é o contrário disso, ou seja, PIVOT.

Comment: nao entendi o que tem haver com a pergunta, eraldo, mas obrigado msm assim

Answer (score -2):

consegui gente, obrigado a todos que respondeu e comentou, vou colocar aqui a forma que fiz pois pode servir de ajuda pra mais alguem com a mesma duvida

```
   select 
   id_produto,
   [codigo1],
   [codigo2],
   [codigo3]

from 
(select 
   id_produto,  
   concat ('codigo',row_number () over (partition by id_produto order by id_produto)) as cont_id,
   codigo_barras

from dbo.produto_sinonimo) as source_table
pivot
(max(codigo_barras)
for 
cont_id in ([codigo1],[codigo2],[codigo3]))
as pivot_table
```

de qualquer forma muito obrigado a todo mundo ae, e principalmente ao motta que me mandou os artigos de quais funções usar.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).